# Highchart first category label is not wrapping

Tags: javascript, highcharts, categories, label, word-wrap

I am facing an issue in Highchart with the category labels, i.e. the first category label of the chart is not wrapping and is overlapping with the second label, whereas rest labels are appearing fine. I have made a demo on jsFiddle, which can explain better : [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvfourbv/).

My code is as follows:

HTML code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#chartContainer').highcharts(
{
    plotOptions: 
    {
    },
    drilldown: 
    {
        series: 
        [
            {
                id: 'Drilldown_749_6',
                index: 0,
                name: 'Y-Axis Label',
                data: [
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 90000
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 710000
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: null
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 1740000
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 800000
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 800000
                    }]
            }
        ],
        drillUpButton: 
        {
            position: 
            {
                y: -3,
                x: -30
            },
            relativeTo: 'spacingBox'
        }
    },
    series: 
    [
        {
            id: 749,
            index: 0,
            visible: true,
            name: 'Y-Axis Label',
            data: [
                {
                    drilldown: 'Drilldown_749_6',
                    name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                    y: 4140000
                }]
        }
    ],
    yAxis: [
        {
            title: 
            {
                text: '<div class=\'ellipsis\' style=\'width:150px;text-align: center;\' title=\'Y-Axis Label\'>Y-Axis Label</div>',
                useHTML: true
            },
            max: 4140000,
            opposite: false,
            gridLineWidth: 1
        }],
    title: 
    {
        text: '<div  class=\'ellipsis\' style=\'width:650px;text-align: center;\' title=\'sdf\'>sdf</div>',
        useHTML: true
    },

    credits: 
    {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: 
    {
        renderTo: 'chartContainer',
        events: 
        {
            drilldown: 
                function ()
                {
                    $('#chartContainer').highcharts().reflow();
                },
            drillup: 
                function ()
                {

                }
        },
        type: 'line'
    },
    xAxis: 
    {
        title: 
        {
            text: 'Category Axis Label',
            margin: 30
        },
        labels: 
        {
            autoRotation: [-20, -40, -80],
            padding: 10
        },
        categories: true,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    exporting: 
    {
        enabled: true
    },
    lang: 
    {
        drillUpText: ' ◁ Back '
    },
    tooltip: 
    {
        pointFormatter: 
            function ()
            {
                var s = '<span style="color:'+this.series.color+'">●</span> '+this.series.name+': <b>'+this.y+'</b>';
                if(typeof this.seriesSettings != "undefined" && typeof this.seriesSettings.tooltipText != "undefined" && this.seriesSettings.tooltipText != "") s = s + ' ['+this.seriesSettings.tooltipText+']';
                return s;
            }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try using these changes of width and useHtml for Xaxis.

```
xAxis: 
    {
         tickInterval: 1,
        title: 
        {
            text: 'Category Axis Label',
            margin: 10
        },
        labels: 
        {   
            autoRotation: [-20, -40, -80],
            padding: 0,
            style: {    
                width : '100px'
                },
            useHTML: true
        },
        categories: true,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
```

Or

You can use this workaround

```
series: 
        [
            {
                id: 'Drilldown_749_6',
                index: 0,
                name: 'Y-Axis Label',
                data: [
                    {
                        name: ' ',
                        y: null
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 90000
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 710000
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: null
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 1740000
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 800000
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yx 123 456 789 0',
                        y: 800000
                    }]
            }
        ],
```

Comment: These work around's, do fix the problem but they doesn't meet my needs.

Comment: But the first option looks fine right .Adding a width to X axis labels .

Comment: But if there are few categories in the chart, than it will also wrap the label even if there is space for label.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like some kind of bug, so it is now reported here - https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4127

As a workaround - you can force redraw by setting chart.isDirtyBox to true and calling chart.redraw after drill down.

```
drilldown: 
            function ()
            {
              setTimeout(function() {
                var chart = $('#chartContainer').highcharts();
                chart.isDirtyBox = true;
                chart.redraw();
              }, 200);
            },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tv6p2549/1/

Comment: Thanks,...This solution worked for me. Hoping highchart will fix it soon.